# does any change in the meaning of the context?

Tags: writing

> Before considering the latest advances in mass spectroscopy, it could be helpful for the readers not accustomed with this field to briefly define what mass spectroscopy is.

Does the above sentence give the same meaning as that given below:

> Before considering the latest advances in mass spectroscopy, briefly defining what mass spectroscopy is could be helpful for the readers not accustomed with this field.

If it is not, how I could change the first sentence with minimal changes to give the meaning of the second sentence

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is about writing advice.

Comment: Note that we say *accustomed **to***, not ***with***; but what you probably mean is ***familiar** with*.

Comment: Contra the above remark, the  concatenation *accustomed with* is used, and in this context it sounds better than *accustomed to*.

Comment: We can ignore all the "writing advice" issues - the actual point being queried is a specific type of garden path construction, which can be addressed without bothering about "proofreading" or "stylistic choice" objections.

Comment: @tosh: If you edit to reflect "writing advice" in comments it's less likely the question will be closed. If you're not around in time to do this and it *does* get closed I might tidy things up myself (you could always revert or alter my edit if you don't like it). I'd vote to reopen, obviously.

Comment: @Stoney and Alan: Thanks to both of you. "Accustomed" should be followed by "to". In this context, I prefer to use the phrase suggested by Alan "familiar with"

Comment: I am confused about the usage of "to infinitive", will the position of this phrase create problem in understanding the intended meaning of the sentence to a general reader?

Comment: "Before considering the latest advances in mass spectroscopy, it could be helpful for readers not familiar with this field if we briefly define what mass spectroscopy is."     will this alteration do?

Comment: It would be fine to explicitly introduce ***we*** as the subject for ***define***. But strictly speaking, ***I*** makes more sense, since the readers aren't going to be doing any defining. Note that I assume there's only a single author, but idiomatically we sometimes use ***we*** even when we actually mean ***I***.

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous error and "flaws" in OP's exact example text, but this is syntactically equivalent...

> 1: *Before I start, it could be helpful for readers who don't know me to briefly explain who I am*
>    2: *Before I start, it could be helpful to briefly explain who I am for readers who don't know me*

In shorter examples like that, native speakers will have no problem understanding the intended meaning of #1, and may not even *notice* anything wrong.

But it's a "garden path" sentence, in that the way native speakers naturally parse the words means we assume the aforementioned ***readers*** will be the subject of the verb following ***to***. Obviously when the very next word is the actual verb ***explain***, we realise straight away that it makes no sense for *readers* to be explaining anything - that's the *speaker/writer's* job. We're briefly mislead into a false parsing pattern, but soon get back on track.

With OP's exact example, the syntactic equivalents are much larger multi-word text strings, meaning the reader spends much *longer* going down the wrong path. *And* he has to go much further back in his "short-term memory" to find an appropriate preceding noun that can serve as the subject of the problematic verb<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> In my case the problematic verb is ***explain*** (the subject of which isn't ***readers who don't know me***, so we have to go further back to find ***I*** (= for **me** to explain). In OP's case, it's ***define***.

Comment: I too find "to define" is problematic.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. The "problem" with your example is that the sequence of the different clauses leads to a parsing error. We start off assuming the ***subject*** of the verb ***define / defining*** will be "the readers not accustomed with this field", but then we realise that doesn't make sense so we have to backtrack and re-interpret the text with ***the writer*** as the subject (because ***he's*** the one who will do the defining, not those readers). Everyone must have this same problem - it's just a matter of how much time/effort they need to figure out how to parse it.